# How should I deal with "No Bootable Devices" during OS install?

Tags: windows, boot

When I start my laptop I get the following error:

> No bootable Devices press <kbd>F1</kbd> to retry, <kbd>F2</kbd> for setup, and <kbd>F3</kbd> for Scan.

When I insert a Windows 7 install CD I get the same problem.

My laptop can't boot from the HDD either.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Before you begin ensure that your physical devices are connected. This involves opening the housing of your computer and checking the cables that connect your HDD / DVD Drive to the motherboard so do not attempt to do so unless you either know what you are doing or don't care if you break something.

1. Enter setup (by pressing F2 when prompted).
2. Look for options called "Boot order", "Boot devices", or similar (this will depend on your   motherboard's BIOS)
3. Ensure that your DVD drive is the first device in the boot order (you should be able to change the order)
4. Save these settings and reboot with the OS setup disk in the DVD drive.

Comment: don't forget to check that the hard disk is actually connected. Happens a lot to me, the hard drive falls out of the slot thanks to vibrations when travelling